# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle timestamp validation fails

Tags: validation, rest, symfony, timestamp, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to send a post request including two timestamps to my REST api. 
The problem is that the timestamps are marked as invalid. "This value is not valid."

What am I doing wrong?

This is the request:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/app_test.php/api/projects/1/tasks/1/timetrackings

Accept: application/json 
Content-Type: application/json

{"timeStart":1390757625,"timeEnd":1390757625,"projectMember":1}
```

The Controller looks as follows:

```
class MemberController extends BaseApiController implements ClassResourceInterface
{
    public function postAction($projectId, $taskId, Request $request)
    {
        /** @var EntityManager $em */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $this->findProject($em, $projectId);
        $task = $this->findTask($em, $projectId, $taskId);

        $request->request->add(array(
            'task' => $taskId,
        ));
        $form = $this->createForm(new TimeTrackType(), new TimeTrack());
        $form->submit($request->request->all());
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            /** @var TimeTrack $tracking */
            $tracking = $form->getData();
            $task->addTimeTrack($tracking);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectView(
                $this->generateUrl('api_get_project_task_timetracking', array(
                    'projectId'  => $projectId,
                    'taskId'     => $taskId,
                    'trackingId' => $tracking->getId(),
                )),
                Codes::HTTP_CREATED
            );
        }
        return View::create($form, Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

The TimeTrackType class:

```
namespace PMTool\ApiBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class TimeTrackType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('timeStart', 'datetime', array(
                'input' => 'timestamp',
            ))
            ->add('timeEnd', 'datetime', array(
                'input' => 'timestamp',
            ))
            ->add('projectMember')
            ->add('task')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PMTool\ApiBundle\Entity\TimeTrack',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'timetrack';
    }
}
```

The entity class:

```
namespace PMTool\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \DateTime;

/**
 * TimeTrack
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PMTool\ApiBundle\Entity\TimeTrackRepository")
 */
class TimeTrack
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="timeStart", type="datetime")
     */
    private $timeStart;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="timeEnd", type="datetime")
     */
    private $timeEnd;


    /**
     * @var ProjectMember
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjectMember")
     */
    private $projectMember;

    /**
     * @var Task
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="timeTracks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="taskId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $task;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set timeStart
     *
     * @param DateTime $timeStart
     * @return TimeTrack
     */
    public function setTimeStart($timeStart)
    {
        $this->timeStart = $timeStart;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get timeStart
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getTimeStart()
    {
        return $this->timeStart;
    }

    /**
     * Set timeEnd
     *
     * @param DateTime $timeEnd
     * @return TimeTrack
     */
    public function setTimeEnd($timeEnd)
    {
        $this->timeEnd = $timeEnd;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get timeEnd
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getTimeEnd()
    {
        return $this->timeEnd;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PMTool\ApiBundle\Entity\Task
     */
    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }

    /**
     * @param \PMTool\ApiBundle\Entity\Task $task
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTask($task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PMTool\ApiBundle\Entity\ProjectMember
     */
    public function getProjectMember()
    {
        return $this->projectMember;
    }

    /**
     * @param \PMTool\ApiBundle\Entity\ProjectMember $projectMember
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProjectMember($projectMember)
    {
        $this->projectMember = $projectMember;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a transformer to achieve this. ([See Symfony Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html))

Here is an Example of my FormType:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToTimestampTransformer;

...

$transformer = new DateTimeToTimestampTransformer();
$builder->add($builder->create('validFrom', 'text')
                ->addModelTransformer($transformer)
        )
```

Be sure to use "'text'" as an input type, otherwise it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

the input option is just for the model side of your underlying data object. In your case it should be datetime.
Your problem is, that you want to transform the timestamp into view data that the symfony form datetime form type does recognise. And I dont know how to do that, unfortunately.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#input